# In AQTime 4, how can performance results be compared when they came from builds installed in different directories?

Tags: comparison, aqtime

For example, if I profile:

```
C:\Program Files\Application Build 1\MyApp.exe
C:\Program Files\Application Build 2\MyApp.exe
```

And I then import both sets of results into a single AQTime project and attempt to compare them, AQTime doesn't match up any of the corresponding functions in each. I'm assuming that while it's comparing, when it comes across two functions with the same name but different module name, it's concluding that they're not the same function and then putting them in separate rows in the output table. How can it be made to ignore the module name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the module names are the same - the difference is in the path. Try disabling the "File names with path" option on the Profiler toolbar (it is shown at the top of the Report panel).
If this does not give the expected results, post here a screenshot demonstrating your situation.

Best regards,
Alex
AutomatedQA Support Team

Comment: Thank you! That button did it. I did get tripped up by one possible issue though - the comparison appears to be case sensitive (I actually had something like MyApp and MyAPP), which I don't normally consider when dealing with files in windows. Once that was fixed, all was well